# Is it possible to connect a USB printer to an Ethernet port?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, usb, printer

Is it possible to connect a USB printer to an Ethernet port by switching some of the wires and attaching them to an end of an ethernet cable, have that go into a wireless router, and through some powerful dark arts and magic have the printer share the printer across the network?

Note: I don't have a network hub that supports a USB going into it and the magic bit. I'm asking is to see if it was possible to maybe install a driver to the router.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because the USB device would require a USB host controller and you'd need the drivers for the USB side of the device. What you're trying to do is pointless when you could just buy a USB print server for a few pounds...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying will not work.

Some routers will have USB ports on them which may allow a printer to be connected.  This would just be using USB and no Ethernet.